# Map XML schemas to xml namespaces in Visual Studio extension

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to make extension for Visual Studio to provide a set of XML Schemas (xsd) mapped to xml namespaces. The set of my XML Schemas is not static and changed (the set and schemas themself).

After some research I did, I know that I can edit this file %VSINSTALLFOLDER%\Xml\Schemas\catalog.xml , However I think it is not a good solution to make a mess in that file. Also, I need different set of xsds for each project.

I beleve that there is a way to set mapping between xsd and xmlns via Visual Studio extension API, but I can not find it.

Comment: You can create your own catalog file if you like, but maybe there is a different way more suitable to your application. Could you provide some trimmed down examples of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Basically, schemas set is generated from some files in a project, so you edit files -> schemas changed. So I want to have completion / errors / editor hints, etc. in xml files in this project as soon as change arrivied. So as you can see xml schemas are project bound and another project can have other schemas with same namespaces, where we will have some sort of collision because we have global catalog for whole Visual Studio